# cannot get like box to appear on website

Tags: facebook-likebox

I have gone through the process of building a like box for my facebook page to link to my website. I have acquired the code however whenever I go to paste the code the placeholder that appears is a tiny square. I am using Xara Web designer to build my website. I have tried everything. I have managed to get a like button to work I think but cannot get the like box to appear on my site.any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot see the like box plugin, you're probably logged into Facebook as a page account and not a user account.  Have a friends try it out for you too.

Another idea is something on your web page is keeping the like box from being rendered.  Strip down your page to bare bones and see if the like box plugin renders.